# Создание файлов с нужным названием

Tags: android

Создаю файл, чтобы в него сохранить изображение из камеры. Делаю так

```
File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + dirName);

try {
    File tmp = File.createTempFile(
            "55555_",      /* prefix */
            ".jpg",  /* suffix */
            direct         /* directory */
    );
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Ном метод createTempFile добавляет после 55555_уникальный набор цифр (видимо текущая дата в формате каком-то). Как создать файл без этих окончаний, а точно с таким же названием как мне нужно?

Comment: не использоваться createTempFile. но если вам надо именно такое создание файла, а проблема лишь в точном названии файла, вытащите целое название файла с "окончанием" через tmp.getName();

Comment: Мне нужно название чтобы название создавалось так: String fileName = "img_" + new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss").format(new Date()) + ".jpg"; а способ создания файла не особо важен, главное чтобы создавался и чтобы мог сохранять фото из камеру в этот файл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
File imageFile = new File(direct, fileName + MyApplication.JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX);
```

Comment: Да, так и сделал. Спасибо). Только хотел написать что так сделал

Comment: Не за что, удачи в разработке )